# Firebase cloud function secret in env file

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

It says in the docs:

> Environment variables stored in .env files can be used for function
> configuration, but you should not consider them a secure way to store
> sensitive information such as database credentials or API keys.

Why is that considered unsecure?

The secret in my case is a 3rd party apy key. If I don't commit the secret to source control, and have the cloud function read the secret from env variables that only I have access to, would you consider that safe enough? I feel using Secret Manager in my case might be an overkill, and am looking to see what you guys think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The complete paragraph in the documentation is this, emphasis mine:

> Environment variables stored in .env files can be used for function configuration, but you should not consider them a secure way to store sensitive information such as database credentials or API keys. **This is especially important if you check your .env files into source control.**

So the primary issue here, from the point of view of the authors of this documentation, is exposing secrets in source control.

If you don't put your .env in source control, it's still possible for someone with access to your Firebase/GCP project (meaning that you gave their google account access to view the console using IAM permissions) to get the .env file you deployed with your function.  It's very common for teams of developers to share access to a project like this, and you might not want every one of them to be able to see this secret data.

The reason why the documentation suggests Secret Manager is because you can use it to give specific individuals the ability to read and write secret values so that you can safely share some aspects of the project with your team, without giving up access to the secrets.  This helps implement the "Principle of Least Privilege", which just a fancy way of saying that every individual should only have access to the specific things that they absolutely need, and nothing more.  And this is big reason why Google Cloud IAM exists.

But if you are the only one who ever has access to any part of your project in the console, you don't have to worry about this.  It's just good to keep in mind the security is a complex issue and it's easy to leak data without fully understanding how individuals can actually get at your data.

Comment: Someone was able to access my API KEY which is in an .env file which has not been uploaded to source control (it is in gitignore) no one but me has access to my Firebase app. I am using Node for Firebase functions. Even every time I change the API KEY it is of no use because they can continue using it. I know that the security issue is complex. Any ideas you recommend?